# How to install Mac OS X from Windows without a CD

Tags: macos, windows-xp, installation, partitioning, operating-systems

I have two partitions, one for windows the other for Mac OS X. Recently, my Mac OS X crashed and my partition rendered unbootable. When I insert Mac OS X's installation CD everything seems normal from startup, to choosing whether to boot from Windows or CD, until the CD boots. The screen flickers and it becomes extremely dark can barely see anything but I can see that it is booted correctly. I tried increasing brightness but that did not work. After hours of trying to read what is on the screen and guessing where to click the installation did not go through... It took more than a couple of hours so I restarted. Now the partition is accessible through Windows but is not bootable.

TL;DR Is it possible to install Mac OS X on a visible partition without the CD through Windows XP?...

Thanks

Comment: You will want to contact Apple for solutions.  You don't mention what version of OSX.  From my understanding it is not possible to "download" OS X unless you are already using OS X.  If you install it from the installation media, and your having a problem, your best solution is to take it to an Apple Care Specialist.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the 90-day warranty call them, however if you dont wipe your entire hardrive. Otherwise just wipe your hardrive and install different bootup system or get a new hardrive, be sure to check what your motherboard supports (e.g. SATA).